# Ошибка в консоли при двойном клике

Tags: vue.js

Пишу код на Vue, выдается ошибка со следующим содержанием:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (event.target.className || "").indexOf is not a function
    at onDoubleClick (eval at success (kernel.js:233), <anonymous>:62:48)
    at dispatch (jquery.js:5237)
    at elemData.handle (jquery.js:5044)
onDoubleClick @ VM7885:62
dispatch @ jquery.js:5237
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:5044
```

Мой код:

```
a(href="#" @click.prevent="handleClick").hero__arrow#scroll-down
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue ({
    el:'#scroll-down',
    methods: {
        handleClick() {
            console.log('ok')
        }
    }
})
```